# Using NSUserdefaults and creating unique people for gallery

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to create gallery of people, to add users to the gallery I would click a "+" a modal pop-over will appear:

2 UITextfield
4 UI Image Views - On press will show Image picker

I would like to know how I can get the UITextfield values and the first UIImage showing on the first screen - whilst also creating a unique person each time?

I've already tried NSUserdefaults but am struggling with creating the unique person and adding it to the first page. How can I append a new person each time to the first page?

[image]

Please only provide Xcode solutions/ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not quite understand your need. But you can store information using a dictionary plist, or if you are storing many users, a database of core data or sqlite.

Or if you want this base is in the cloud, you can use icloud, parse or dropbox database.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/read-and-write-dictionaries-arrays-strings-as-property-lists.html

Comment: Will using a dictionary plist allow me to output unique people onto a viewcontroller? like shown on the left of this image? http://i61.tinypic.com/65y7f9.png

Comment: Plist work like a database, you can read your plist to an array, each position on array can be a people.